# What does the |= operator do?

Tags: php, operator-keyword

I saw this operator `|=` in another question and I wondered what it does. It looks like this:

```
 $result |= (ord($safe[$i % $safeLen]) ^ ord($user[$i]));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a combined operator: [assignment(`=`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) and a [OR operator(`|`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). It's the same as:

```
$result = $result | (ord($safe[$i % $safeLen]) ^ ord($user[$i]));
```

Bitwise OR(inclusive) operator `|`:

```
  a  |  b  |  result
---------------------
  0  |  0  |   0
  1  |  0  |   1
  0  |  1  |   1
  1  |  1  |   1
```

Bitwise XOR(exclusive) operator `^`:

```
  a  |  b  |  result
---------------------
  0  |  0  |   0
  1  |  0  |   1
  0  |  1  |   1
  1  |  1  |   0
```

Comment: Seems like it ought to feature on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)